# How to show sectionHeader in JSWheelView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to show section titles in each section instead of lines in JSWheelView. It seems like some methods are already implemented but commented out here. Please help me for the same.

We can found the code from here https://github.com/l2eshock/JSWheelView